# Есть ли эквивалент SQL Server функции IsNull() в Oracle?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, plsql, null

В  SQL Server можно воспользоваться функцией [`IsNull(expression, replacement)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), чтобы опредилить, является ли результат выражения `NULL`, и замениить его алтернативным значением в этом случае.

Есть ли эквивалент функции [`IsNull()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) в Oracle?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/3523036/6571020

Answer (score 6):

Нет, 100%-го эквивалента функции `IsNull()` в *Oracle* не существует.

---

Рекомендуемый аналог [`COALESCE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COALESCE.html#GUID-3F9007A7-C0CA-4707-9CBA-1DBF2CDE0C87), входит в стандарт ANSI/ISO SQL, поддерживается всеми известными брендами СУБД включая *SQL Server*.
Отличия:

- `COALESCE` в отличии от `IsNull()` может принимать любое количество аргументов, первое `NOT NULL` выражение будет возвращено как результат.
- В *Oracle* все выступающие как аргументы выражения в `COALESCE` должны иметь один тип данных. То есть, следующие запросы в *SQL Server* выполнятся:

  ```
  select isNull(1, 'NaN') res
  select coalesce (1, 2, '123', 3)
  ```

  , а в *Oracle* нет:

  ```
  select coalesce (1, 2, '123', 3) from dual;
  ```

  > ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR

Есть также не стандартный аналог [`NVL()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/NVL.html#GUID-3AB61E54-9201-4D6A-B48A-79F4C4A034B2). Но имеет важное отличие - *short-circuit evaluation* в нём не доступно, т.е. алтернативное выражение для замены будет выполнено даже, если проверяемое выражение вернёт `NOT NULL`. Такие запросы:

```
select isNull(1, 1/0) res
select coalesce (1, 1/0) res from dual;
```

выполнятся без ошибки, а такой нет:

```
select nvl (1, 1/0) from dual;
```

> ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero

---

Описанные выше функции применимы в PL/SQL контексте и их поведение ничем не отличается от выполнения в SQL контексте.